# going to target and home within one tick

Tags: netlogo

I want my turtles to go to a target and go home again (using `fd`) within the time period of one tick. The model works fine when I execute the go procedure one by one ("go once"). Execution as a loop (without altering the code), however, doesn't work: The turtles don't move; the tick counter is updated though. It seems that the functions are executed correctly but the movement is not visualized. Thanks for your help!

```
to go
  if ticks >= 365 [ stop ]
  move
  if not any? turtles with [ shape = "person" and movement-done? = false ]
  [
    tick
    ask turtles with [ shape = "person" ] [
      set movement-done? false
      set reached? false
      set at-home-again? false ]
  ]

end


to move

  ask turtles with [ shape = "person" ]
  [
    if movement-done? = false
    [
      ifelse reached? = false
      [
        ifelse patch-here = target [ set reached? true set at-home-again? false ]
        [
          face target
          fd 1
        ]
      ]
      [
        ifelse at-home-again? = false
        [
          ifelse patch-here = myhome [ show "patch-here = myhome" set at-home-again? true ]
          [
            face myhome
            fd 1
          ]
        ]
        [
        set movement-done? true
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

end
```

Comment: I should add that I don't get an error, so the syntax should be okay. It's just not running, nothing happens when I press 'go'. I also tried while-loops but they didn't work either. If you have suggestions on how to solve this problem, I'd be glad.

Comment: One suggestion is to put print statements throughout your code to see what's being triggered---though, this is just general advice.

Comment: @mattsap Thanks. Didn't solve my problem but might clearifiy what's wrong (not for me though ;)). See what I appended to the original question above -- any idea?

Comment: I would suggest to put print statements in your move function. Particularly, between the if statements to see which ones are being executed. You're probably not setting your target triggers correctly and they're always one value. Particularly,  set movement-done? is never set to true which then never ticks.

Comment: @mattsap Thanks again, but the move functions works correctly, it seems. If I press go once every turtle moves and after a couple times they have moved to their target and back home. When all turtles are at home again, the tick counter is advanced by 1. This is the point where it stops working. But according to the print statements I put into the go function everything should be fine: Before move is executed, all turtles have movement-done set to false. Directly after move it's 0, and after the tick its all turtles again. As it should be. The ticks are advanced but the turtles stop moving.

Comment: Okay, I see what was wrong with the go once problem now. I forgot to also set `reached?` and `at-home-again?` to false again. A big problem remains, however: If I execute the code with "go once" it works wonderfully (now at least) but the turtles don't move when I execute go as a loop. The ticks are advanced but it seems that this is just too computation-intensive for Netlogo to visualize?

Comment: I’m not following your reasoning there about “computation-intensive”

Comment: @SethTisue Hi, I updated the question above and stripped off the obsolete parts. I still wonder how it can be that the same code works with "go once" but doesn't with "go".